# DRF: How to add authentication and permissions info from class-based views into autogenerated documentation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, core-api

In Django Rest Framework you can simply generate documentation:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/#documenting-your-api

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title'))
]
```

Autogenerated documentation has request body nicely generated from serializer, nice documentation from docs but how to add authentication and permission classes information?

Some of my class-based views have custom `authentication_classes` and `permission_classes` and how to display information about them?

Answer (score 0):

Look into `include_docs_urls` will see this:

```py
def include_docs_urls(
        title=None, description=None, schema_url=None, public=True,
        patterns=None, generator_class=SchemaGenerator,
        authentication_classes=api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES,
        permission_classes=api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES,
        renderer_classes=None):
    ....
```

So, the solution is:

**Setup the `authentication_classes` & `permission_classes` in settings.py**

- Sample authentication_classes:

```py
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',  # <---- 1
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'common.permissions.IsDeveloper',   # <---- 2 don't forget the ','
    )
}
```

> Note:
>   1. SessionAuthentication is needed because **DRF Self describing APIs** use session to keep user login
>   2. `common.permissions.IsDeveloper` is a custom permission class you can define your self and put the reference location as a string here, you can use default permission too.

- Sample permission class:

```py
# common/permissions.py

class IsDeveloper(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user_groups = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
        return bool('Developer' in user_groups)
```

Then if you didn't login or login user not in 'Developer' Group, will come to:

[image]

Comment: you may want to override this error page template: at rest_framework/docs/error.html.